# Adding a very large vector image

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I need some advice on how to add vector image data to my WPF application. As of now, I simply add the image information as StreamGeometry to the UserControl resources. For example:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <StreamGeometry x:Key="ProtoLeaf" >m 451.45 512 c 17.06 0 30.43 -13.86 30.43 -31.56 V 31.55 C 481.87 13.86 468.51 0 451.44 0 A 32.94 32.94 0 0 0 434.99 4.52 L 46.29 229 c -10.13 5.85 -16.18 16 -16.18 27 0 11 6 21.2 16.18 27 l 388.7 224.48 a 32.92 32.92 0 0 0 16.45 4.52 z</StreamGeometry>
        <StreamGeometry x:Key="ProtoFrog">m 51.45 512 c 17.06 0 30.43 -13.86 30.43 -31.56 V 31.55 C 481.87 13.86 468.51 0 451.44 0 A 32.94 32.94 0 0 0 434.99 4.52 L 46.29 229 c -10.13 5.85 -16.18 16 -16.18 27 0 11 6 21.2 16.18 27 l 388.7 224.48 a 32.92 32.92 0 0 0 16.45 4.52 z</StreamGeometry>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And then I use these for my path objects.

```
<Viewbox Margin="97,10,10,10">
    <Canvas x:Name="Pond" Background="#FF58CFF1" Margin="4" Height="360" Width="640">
        <Path x:Name="Leaf1" Tag="1" Height="80" Width="80" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FF30F012" Data="{DynamicResource ProtoLeaf}">
        </Path>
```

I created a couple of fairly large vector images and I have the StreamGeometry data available, but it is HUGE. Thousands of lines, and it breaks the syntax highlighting in visual studio. I don't really know how am I supposed to handle this?

Comment: Since you mention Visual Studio syntax highlighting... is the main problem the Visual Studio Designer at development or is there a problem with the compiled app?

Comment: It is really just the highlighting. The code still compiles and works fine.

Comment: Maybe it's enough to create a separate `ResourceDictionary` file with the geometries, reference it in the usercontrol, add the vector data, close it and never open it again. This *might* be enough. Otherwise you can try to load the data as a dynamic resource only after checking `DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode`, so you won't see anything about it in the designer but you get some usability in return.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after thinking about grek40's comment and doing some research in this direction I came up with the following solution. I simply added a MergedDictionaries statement and reference an external file where I have all my SteamGeometry information.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/imagefiles/VectorCollection.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: The designer can be a bit sensible at times... good to know this worked for you.